# Hard freeze Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, freeze

I am facing this issue from around 3 - 4 months.My PC used to restart anytime for no specific reason and event id in event viewer was shown 41 .My PC specs was then
Asus Motherboard M5A78L-M LX3
AMD Phenom II X3
4 GB RAM
1 GB AMD 6450 GPU
500 GB HDD Windows 7
Had it checked with my Engineer, which then turned out to be some conflicts with my Processor and motherboard.Switched to Intel Pentium Dual CPU E2160 @ 1.8 Ghz with Gigabyte GA-G41MT S2P with same RAM and HDD.But now the crashes and freezes are too frequent with same error id and I am unable to work anything
Please help out.
Thanks in Advance.

Event Log

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
<Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power" Guid="{331C3B3A-2005-
 44C2-AC5E-77220C37D6B4}" />
<EventID>41</EventID>
<Version>2</Version>
<Level>1</Level>
<Task>63</Task>
<Opcode>0</Opcode>
<Keywords>0x8000000000000002</Keywords>
<TimeCreated SystemTime="2016-10-22T02:25:08.151524200Z" />
<EventRecordID>6267</EventRecordID>
<Correlation />
<Execution ProcessID="4" ThreadID="8" />
<Channel>System</Channel>
<Computer>Akash-PC</Computer>
</System>
- <EventData>
<Data Name="BugcheckCode">0</Data>
<Data Name="BugcheckParameter1">0x0</Data>
<Data Name="BugcheckParameter2">0x0</Data>
<Data Name="BugcheckParameter3">0x0</Data>
<Data Name="BugcheckParameter4">0x0</Data>
<Data Name="SleepInProgress">false</Data>
<Data Name="PowerButtonTimestamp">0</Data>
</EventData>
</Event>
```

Even after that switched to a Core 2 Duo CPU with clean format for full hdd and reinstalled Windows.But still there are hard freezes.Restart / Freeze at Windows loading logo.
OS : Windows 10 (currently)

Thanks in adv.

EDIT #1:
These are the files after running HD Tune:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/9dla5c38cy0ex41/AAC_t3Ah3qdAPIWcBJj7GJhTa?dl=0

If this can help out

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2028504/en-us

Comment: magicandre1981 thanks..but I had a look at this long back.Its not acting as a solution.

Comment: check all steps from the support page and look what applies to you. such things are nearly impossible for us to answer

Comment: Ok @magicandre... Will revert to u on that soon

Comment: @magicandre:My issue belongs to Scenario 3 in that support page as my PC is completely unresponsive and then I have to shut down the PC using power button for long which is Scenario 2 in the support page.What can be done.

Comment: ok, press CAPS LOCK key during the freeze and look if status light on keyboard toggles or not. if not, you have a HW based freeze. if the light does toggle, you have a freeze caused by a buggy driver.

Comment: @magicandre caps lock does not toggle during the freeze

Comment: ok, so you have a HW based freeze. check all HW componnets (CPU, memory) for errors, unplug USB devices until you see which device causes the freeze

Comment: @magicandre:ok unplugging usb devices can be done..but how shall i detect issues within cpu or memory...that too with trial /error basis? Which i feel is impossible

Comment: test the Intel CPU with the [diag tool from Intel](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/19792/Intel-Processor-Diagnostic-Tool), check the [RAM with memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org/)

Comment: @magicandre1981:this is the link for intel diag check results : https://www.dropbox.com/s/uvn3bji7kx7qk6q/TestResults_Full.txt?dl=0
It failed at two places at SPBC and BrandString.Please let me know what could be the issue, if any idea regarding the same.And config were defaults nothing touched.

Comment: have you also tried memtest86+?

Comment: @magicandre1981: Yes only for 1 pass.Then closed it as I had to go out for some work.Will perform the 8 pass test soon and revert. Btw 1 pass had no issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The most likely cause of your failure is the PSU.**

Code 41 in English means Windows does not know why it shut down. It is caused by things like power failures, holding the power button down to shut off the computer, overheating and other errors.

You should not have changed the MB and CPU, but since you did, those are nearly excluded.

RAM and HDD are easy to test with Memtestx86 and HDTune.

Comment: With the changed MB and processor I am trying to get through a complete memtest atleast and I am unable to complete that @overmind. I have done many trial and error work dave but strange aspect is the pc worked fine at my engineer s home that too at a stretch of 60 hrs appx i guess but gave issues at my place after a week or two.And I am speaking abt the latest h.w config

Comment: Variations on the power grid could be noticed quite a lot if the PSU is at it's limit.

Comment: dint get you what you are trying to say...can you please elaborate

Comment: If the PSU is at it's limit (or dying), any small variation in the quality of the power lines will make it restart.

Comment: Ok... thanks Overmind..actually the PSU seems old..I ll have a check with that..but any manual thing which i can do outside the machine for PSU to reproduce that issue of restart what you mentioned?

Comment: Starting stuff with motors like high power vacuum cleaners should cause a slight power variations and bad capacitors from a PSU won't handle the down-spike. Tests should be done when the grid is at highest load (usually in the evening).

Comment: Performed memtestx86 with 8 passes and no errors..Just check this image : Memtestx86 https://imgur.com/gallery/lSSZU

Comment: Looks like it's fine.

Comment: So what is the final check i can do.Does that mean it is SMPS issue or basically power issue

Comment: Most likely power issue.

Comment: Ok thanks @Overmind. Will check with SMPS and sockets again.

Comment: Overmind changing the PSU worked.Thanks.As of long time I havent faced any freezes.But after using my AMD 6450 graphics card with it the PC shows message : "The current input timing is not supported by the monitor display.Please change it to 1920*1080 @60Hz" which was already the config.Also display showed various pink green lines and I had to restart.Giving my graphics card for check with a technician

Comment: Glad it works. As for the display message, there should not be anything wrong with the video card. Probably it has a setting not supported by your monitor. Set your display to something basic (1024*768*60Hz) and then try a higher resolution. Usually the error comes from the refresh rate (higher setting than the monitor supports).

Comment: Actually I am running my pc on 1024*768 at 60hz all these days... After installing my gpu card that resolution error popped at 1920*1080 at 60hz.And today I gave my card to technician and got to know its IC has failed.Need to buy new GPU card :(

Comment: Well, after installing drivers, Windows automatically changes the res to the one it considers best. This sometimes has bad consequences, even if rarely.

Comment: Just after the day i wrote to u I had hard freeze the next day..and today i thot to install ubuntu to check if that runs well..while shrinking c drive it converted to dynamic disk..and now the freeze is quite frequent..damn confused now.

Answer (score 0):

From what you've described my first place would have been the PSU, and not advise you to change all the hardware as you have done...

See if you can borrow a different PSU and see how it goes.

Since you've added new hardware I am going to assume that all cables are connected correctly.

The other thing is to remove all devices which are not needed, such as any additional USB devices or additional storage.

Sadly, these types of issues are often solved via trial and error.

Comment: I have changed PSU twice...and mainly the PC worked fine at my engineer place for 60 hrs at stretch..but failed at my place in a week or two

Comment: Anything about the environment? It's it hot room, humid room, beside a train track?

Comment: Lol..No...it isnt so hot..But yeah the weather sometimes is bit hot that's all coz of the overall temperature of city and not the temp at my place.

Comment: Have you checked for Power Fluctuations? Do you have Lights Bulbs with continuously varying their intensity?

Comment: I've seen other posts which have said it turned out to be environment (be it unreliant power supply, living near something which caused high vibration). I admit though, it *was* a "long shot". Take it back to the engineers house, if it fails again then you know it's still hardware

Comment: @AEonAX:Bulbs dont fluctuate at my home as per your description.

Comment: @Dave:ok i take to engineer s house and if it doesnt fail again as last time then what maybe the issue... My home power supply?

Comment: Tried installing a new PSU but still there's occurence of hard freeze @Overmind and Dave